# Vb Combo Box Populated by SQL Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

Hi Guys I'm trying to create a combo box populated by SQL Query, however my code below is not displaying any result whenever i click the Drop Down, Please Help me. Merci

```
Private Sub eNumText_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles eNumText.SelectedIndexChanged

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= c:\Databse\Company_db.accdb"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EmpID from tbl_empinfo"

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read
            eNumText.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
        End While
        dr.Close()
```

Comment: 5 questions with LOTS of detailed help and 0 accepted answers...clicking the dropdown will not trigger this code to run

Comment: we came here to seek for help not to be trash talked @Plutonix , Some of Users are newbies unlike you, you're super hardcore  programmer

Comment: what trash talk?  I just spent **2 hours** giving you an answer you just got an hour before that.  you've gotten gobs of help...and havent acknowledged a single one

Comment: Your doing it on index changed. If there's no items you won't even trigger that event and not execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not be fired, becuase I guess there is no Items in the ComboBox, move your code to a Button_Click or Form_Load event and it will work:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  'Your Code
   ....
End Sub
```